# Information about widget context/lifecycle

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I've a widget that is packaged in an application and I've several doubts about the context/lifecycle of the widget/application:

- The application and widget share the same process, and consecuently singletons?
- If I've services they have to be remote ones?
- What's the lifecycle of the process that updates the widget? Is only for the widget?

In general any information about the widget lifecycle/context would be very apreciated

Comment: isn't this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html enough?

Comment: No, I had read it and I'm not able to answer to my questions with that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application and widget share the same process

If you look at your code, you will find a class that extends `AppWidgetProvider`, in all likelihood. This is the code that updates the home screen UI for the portion of it taken up by your app widget.

If you look at your manifest, you will see that you added your `AppWidgetProvider` as a `<receiver>`. This indicates that `AppWidgetProvider` is a `BroadcastReceiver`. Manifest-registered `BroadcastReceivers` live for a very short time -- long enough to process `onReceive()`, and that's about it.

Hence, it is possible that "the application and widget share the same process" momentarily, insofar as if you already have a process (e.g., the user is inside one of your activities right now), and `onUpdate()` of your `AppWidgetProvider` is triggered, then the `AppWidgetProvider` will be in that same process. However, if your application is not running, then `onUpdate()` for your `AppWidgetProvider` will run in some process, which may or may not have hosted any of your code before.

> and consecuently singletons?

You should not rely upon this.

> If I've services they have to be remote ones?

Absolutely not, for any definition of "remote".

> What's the lifecycle of the process that updates the widget? Is only for the widget?

See above.

Comment: I understand that I haven't to use remote services because it's guaranted that if in some moment the application and the WidgetProvider are running at the same time they will be sharing the process?

Comment: @lujop: Yes. That being said, you cannot know ahead of time if your `AppWidgetProvider` is running in the same process with anything else. That is one of a few reasons why `AppWidgetProvider` should use `startService()` to communicate with services.